# Irreale Wunschsätze - nur vs doch

Tags: subjunctive

I'm currently working my way through Hueber's "Sag's besser" exercise book, and I'm struggling to master exercise 28:

In the exercise, I am supposed to form a conditional sentence such as "Wenn er doch/nur mehr Zeit hätte!", or "Wäre sie doch/nur weggefahren!". The fist time I attempted this, I thought that doch & nur would be equally applicable in every sentence, but the answer-key makes it clear that sometimes only one is applicable. For example the following correct answers are given:

1. [Rainer blieb in der teuren Wohnung. (*ausziehen*)] -> Wäre er **doch/nur** ausgezogen!
2. [Sie briet den Fisch zu kurz.] -> Hätte sie ihn **doch/nur** länger gebraten!
3. [Leider darf der Patient noch nicht aufstehen.] -> Wenn er **nur** schon aufstehen dürfte!
4. [Leider wurde nichts gefunden.] -> Wäre **nur** etwas gefunden worden!
5. [Uta versuchte es nur zweimal.] -> Hätte sie es **doch** öfter versucht!
6. [Leider hat die Bank schon zu.] -> Hätte sie **doch** noch offen!

with the guidance "Bilden Sie Wunschsätze und verwenden Sie dabei Pronomen. Bilde Sie die Vergangenheitsformen ohne die Konjuktion *wenn*".

In total there are 24 such sentences, and looking over all of them, I cannot figure out why, for example, sometime nur is only applicable (as in 3. and 4.), sometimes only doch (as in 5. and 6.), and sometimes both (1. and 2.).

Is there a pattern to this? Because, for example, "Hätte sie es **nur** öfter versucht!" sounds OK to me, but according to the book, it is wrong!

Comment: Very good question. I'm a native speaker and I have no idea what the pattern is. I even think that "doch nur" (both combined) doesn't sound too bad in most of the examples (but that might be colloquial/regional).

Comment: Note that ‚bloß‘ is another word that one could try to untangle. My intuitions say that it works in each of the six sample sentences. (As do 'doch bloß' and 'nur bloß'.) It also just about works in the Helga-Satz in the post by @Christian Geiselmann, but I don’t think it works in his sentences about the Bauprojekt.

Comment: Ask the author of the book. I don't see it justified.

Comment: Which volume of *Sag's besser*? I think there were six of them.

Comment: After thinking some time about this I agree @userunknown that the author should be asked about this. There seems to be some minor difference, but for me it seems like it is just about personal preferences...

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe "Teil 1" ISBN: 978-3-19-007453-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anfänglich ging es wie dem Kommentator Annatar: Ich bin ein Muttersprachler, und ich konnte zunächst nicht erkennen, wo der Unterschied zwischen *doch* und *nur* in den Beispielsätzen liegen sollte und nach welchen Kriterien man hie das eine, hie das andere verwenden müsste. Für mein Gefühl waren *doch* und *nur* in allen diesen Sätzen austauschbar.

> Wäre nur etwas gefunden worden!
>
> Wäre doch etwas gefunden worden!

Dann habe ich es mit einem Praxistest versucht. Stellen wir uns eine konkrete Situation vor:

Zwei Bergbauspezialisten sitzen in der Kneipe und unterhalten sich über die Projekte ihrer Firma in den vergangenen Jahren.

> A: Weißt du noch, das große Projekt da am Mühlenberg? Das war ja ein Ding!
>
> B: Ja, so ein Riesenaufwand, den Tunnel da zum Fraxental zu bohren!
>
> A: Und was ist dabei rausgekommen? Nichts! Kein Quentchen Gold gefunden.
>
> B: Millionen hat das gekostet.
>
> A: Wäre nur etwas herausgekommen dabei! Dann hätte sich der ganze Aufwand wenigstens gelohnt!

Tja. Hm. Nun sehe ich: Da scheint doch ein Unterscheid zu sein. "Wäre doch etwas dabei herausgekommen" funktioniert in diesem Beispiel nicht. Warum? "Wäre doch etwas herausgekommen" würde man sagen, wenn mit dem vermissten Ereignis ein inniglicher persönlicher Wunsch verbunden ist (wofür wir im Bergbau-Beispiel keinen Anhaltspunkt haben). "Wäre nur etwas dabei herausgekommen" scheint dagegen eine neutralere Haltung des Sprechers nahezulegen. Nicht ganz neutral natürlich, denn das Urteil "Die ganze Aktion war sinnlos, denn das erhoffte, entscheidende Ziel wurde nicht erreicht" wird ja trotzdem geäußert, aber - so scheint mir - von einer etwas distanzierteren Warte, also mit weniger persönlicher Betroffenheit.

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> (1) Helga wollte so gerne mit Emil zusammenkommen, aber irgendwie schien er ihre Annäherungsversuche nicht wahrnzunehmen. Hätte sie es **nur** öfter versucht!
>
> (2) Helga wollte so gerne mit Emil zusammenkommen, aber irgendwie schien er ihre Annäherungsversuche nicht wahrnzunehmen. Hätte sie es **doch** öfter versucht!

Der Unterschied ist kaum wahrnehmbar, aber vielleicht gibt es ihn doch. In (1) könnte man herauslesen: "Hätte sie es nur öfter versucht, wäre sie vielleicht doch noch an ihn herangekommen", aber mehr im Sinne einer neutralen Feststellung. In (2) vermittelt das *doch* dass dies im Nachhinein der intensive Wunsch (samt Selbstvorwürfen) Helgas ist, also beladen mit mehr Gefühl, aber mit weniger Sicherheit, dass die Annäherungsversuche dann Erfolg gehabt hätten.

Teilt ihr diese Einschätzung? Lässt sich der Gedanke noch klarer fassen?

Auf die Frage bezogen müsste man dann aber sagen: Man kann nicht einfach einen Satz ankucken und dann entscheiden, ob *doch* oder *nur* oder beide hier möglich wären. Man muss den Kontext kennen.

---

**Later:**

Based on Marx Oxford's contribution plus his commenters', I start thinking whether we could reduce the difference of meaning to a simple pair of juxtaposed notions such as *moral vs factual*, or *moral vs. causal* proposition:

Moral proposition:

> Hätte sie doch den Kuchen gegessen, dann wäre dieses Unglück nicht passiert

Causal proposition:

> Hätte sie nur den Kuchen gegessen, dann wäre das Unglück nicht passiert.

(In my initial attempt of an aswer, the pair would be "emotionally engaged vs not emotionally engaged")

**Bonus question**

We so far completely ingored that also "doch nur" is possible - and in use:

> Hätte sie doch  nur den Kuchen gegessen, dann wäre das Unglück nicht passiert.

Now what's this? Moral and factual proposition? Emotional and non-emotional? The latter makes no sense, so "moral vs. factual" is the more operational pair.

Comment: In deinem zweiten Beispiel (dem mit Helga) klingt das durchaus nachvollziehbar. Andererseits sind gerade die beiden "nur"-Beispiele des Fragestellers tendenziell eher emotional statt neutral. Vor allem im vierten kann man sich gut Situationen mit großer persönlicher Betroffenheit vorstellen, aber in dem Fall klingt "doch" finde ich tatsächlich etwas schräg. Schwierig..

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann very interesting idea. Thanks to everybody contributing here, I'm beginning to build a stronger idea of when each is more likely to be used. I have now edited my original post to include the 'original' questions from the text book, because they give the only context from which I am supposed to make my assessment. It looks like 3. and 5. can have your patterns easily applied. But to me it looks like 4. and 6. should be free to have either doch or nur (as the context is quite weak and doesn't indicate either viewpoint), so it's still not fully clear to me.

Comment: @Matt   I went through your sample pairs of sentences. I tested the answers given by inserting *doch* and *nur* (independent of the allegedly "correct" answers). I find that in all of them I can use both. So there is no "correct" answer. It simply depends on: do you want to tell a "factual" or an "emotional" message (using the terminology developed in my answer). In that situation, I start thinking wouldn't it be a good idea to confront the author of the book with these findings? Perhaps he/she comes up with a reasonable argument in defence of his/her claim. But I don't see it so far.

Answer (score 6):

I’m also a native, and agree that the difference (if any) is rather subtle. However, here’s a (rather slim) linguistic intuition I have about these cases:

The ‘doch’ sentences express a complaint: He *should have* moved out; she *should have* fried it longer; she *should have* tried it more often; they *should still* be open. You are unhappy with the situation, and saying that you don’t understand why they aren’t still open etc.

By contrast, the ‘nur’ sentences suggest a solution to the problem, without implying fault. At least, the implication isn’t as strong. E.g. in 3, you’re not complaining about the doctors, and aren’t saying that they should let him get out of bed already. You’re just saying: *if* they let him, he wouldn’t be so miserable – but you get why they won’t let him.

I think this also fits with Christian Geiselmann’s second example. (Not so sure about the first.) With ‘nur’, the speaker seems to just be saying that it is a pity she didn’t try harder. With ‘doch’, it’s suggested that Helga made a mistake.

If we move away from conditionals, we see the difference again in e.g. (i) vs (ii):

(i) Versuch es nur weiter!

(ii) Versuch es doch weiter!

Here (i) sounds much more encouraging and gentler than (ii), and (ii) sounds like an admonition.

Btw, Does Hueber not state a rule before setting the exercise?

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me. It does not explain why the book doesn't accept "Hätte sie es nur öfter versucht!" though (which in turn is a completely fine sentence to me, so there is that..).

Comment: @Annatar. I agree it’s odd he doesn’t accept that. My suggestion in essence predicts that most of the time, *either* works. It just depends on whether you want to place blame or just express regret. This would then also explain why we initially all thought that the original sentences don’t have unique solutions. It unfortunately doesn't explain what 'doch nur' means.

Comment: I think it's simply the sum of both, blame and regret (with a higher tendency to use it for one's own actions). So, if we compare by "accusation intensity", it's  nur < doch < doch nur. Maybe.

Comment: @MarkOxford, thanks for your answer. Your example with "Versuch es..." is actually pretty clear and is really helping. With regards to the Hueber 'rule' given: I've added the only instruction given to my original post, and also included the original 'promoting' questions for each line.

Comment: I am not native, but this answer matches the intuition I have developed over the years. Modal particles were one of the most difficult aspects of the language for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Als erstes fiel mir beim Durchlesen der Frage auf, dass ich in den aufgeführten Beispielsätzen wahrscheinlich weder *doch* noch *nur*, sondern *doch nur* verwendet hätte: "Wäre er *doch nur* ausgezogen!"

Beim Abwägen zwischen *doch* und *nur* hatte ich zwar das Gefühl, dass die Wahl einen Unterschied bewirken würde. Worin er jedoch bestand, war mir auf Anhieb selbst nicht klar. Deswegen habe ich jeden Beispielsatz meinem "Spachgefühltest" unterzogen.

Dabei fiel mir auf, dass je nach Wahl sich auch die Intonation ändert, mit der der Satz gesprochen werden würde. Im folgenden habe ich daher diejenige Silbe, auf die die höchste Tonlage des Satzes fällt (=betont), **fett** hervorgehoben - manchmal gibt es zwei Betonungen; andere Betonungen schienen mir nicht möglich bzw. nicht sinnvoll. Oft hat eine Variante auch eine inhaltliche Vervollständigung erfordert; in solchen Fällen habe ich sie immer ergänzt. Manchmal war die Vervollständigung nicht zwingend notwendig, aber zur Veranschaulichung des Kontextes hilfreich; in solchen Fällen habe ich sie in Klammern ergänzt.

1. "Wäre er doch ausgezogen!" vs. "Wäre er nur ausgezogen!"

   > Wäre er **doch** ausgezo**gen**, hätte er sie nie kennengelernt.

Satzmelodie zur Veranschaulichung (erstellt anhand einer Sprachaufnahme, grüne Linie stellt den Tonverlauf dar): [image]

Hier wird rückblickend ausgedrückt, dass er sich in der Vergangenheit dazu entschieden hat, *nicht* auszuziehen. Zusätzlich wird die Folge davon ausgedrückt, was passiert wäre, wenn er doch (= entgegen der getroffenen Entscheidung) *anders* gehandelt hätte. Damit ist nicht notwendigerweise eine Bewertung verbunden, welche der Entscheidungen vorzuziehen gewesen wäre.
Der Satz ist gleichwertig zu: "Wenn er ausgezogen wäre, hätte er sie nie kennengelernt."

Anders die *nur*-Variante:

> Wäre er nur **aus**gezogen! (Dann wäre ihm der ganze Ärger erspart geblieben.)

Hier wird die Entscheidung, nicht auszuziehen, bereut (und somit stillschweigend eine negative Folge dieser Entscheidung unterstellt).

Zwar geht das auch in der *doch*-Variante, jedoch scheint sie mir weniger gebräuchlich zu sein; ich persönlich würde jedenfalls die obige *nur*-Variante vorziehen:

> Wäre er doch **aus**gezogen! (Dann wäre ihm der ganze Ärger erspart geblieben.)

2. "Hätte sie ihn doch länger gebraten!" vs. "Hätte sie ihn nur länger gebraten!"

   > Hätte sie ihn **doch** länger gebra**ten**, wäre er knuspriger geworden.

   Hier wird rückblickend ausgedrückt, dass sie sich in der Vergangenheit dazu entschieden hat, den Fisch *nicht* länger zu braten. Zusätzlich wird die Folge davon ausgedrückt, was passiert wäre, wenn sie doch (= entgegen der getroffenen Entscheidung) *anders* gehandelt hätte. Auch hier ist damit nicht notwendigerweise eine Bewertung verbunden, welche der Entscheidungen vorzuziehen gewesen wäre. Der Satz ist gleichwertig zu: "Wenn sie den Fisch länger gebraten hätte, wäre er knuspriger geworden."

Anders die *nur*-Variante:

> Hätte sie ihn nur **län**ger gebraten! (Dann hätte sie sich am Fisch nicht vergiftet.)

Hier wird die Entscheidung, den Fisch nicht länger gebraten zu haben, bereut (und somit stillschweigend eine negative Folge dieser Entscheidung unterstellt).

Zwar geht das auch in der *doch*-Variante, jedoch scheint sie mir weniger gebräuchlich zu sein; ich persönlich würde auch hier die obige *nur*-Variante vorziehen:

> Hätte sie ihn doch **län**ger gebraten! (Dann hätte sie sich am Fisch nicht vergiftet.)

3. bis 6. analog

Die Varianten mit "doch nur" sind gleichbedeutend mit den *nur*-Varianten.

Im Ergebnis kann ich im Gegensatz zum Exercise Book keinen Unterschied in der Nutzung von "doch" vs. "nur" in den Beispielsätzen erkennen.